# Loading music into pygame using tkSnack

Tags: python, load, pygame

I'm trying to load music into a python file using tkSnack
Here is my code

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import tkSnack
root = tk.Tk()
tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)
snd = tkSnack.Sound() 
mysound.read('c:/Python27/Shingeki no Kyojin -Attack on Titan- - Opening 1, 2.mp3') 
mysound.play()
```

However it keeps showing me this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\Desktop\game.py", line 6, in <module>
    tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)
  File "C:\Users\George\Desktop\tkSnack.py", line 21, in initializeSnack
    Tkroot.tk.call('eval', 'package require snack')
TclError: can't find package snack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pygame.mixer.music.load("c:/Python27/Shingeki no Kyojin -Attack on Titan- - Opening 1, 2.mp3")`to load your music file.

To play the music use : `pygame.mixer.music.play()`

also see : [pygame module for controlling stream audio](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play)